# What is the benefit of using protractor for applications non angular?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm currently implementing automated tests and would like to know what are the benefits of automating non-angular applications with protractor.

What are the advantages comparing with the use only of webdriverJS?

Answer (score 2):

`protractor` provides a [convenient and well-designed API](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api) and an abstraction layer over the `WebDriverJS` javascript selenium bindings. It is actively developed and maintained by Google developers.

Aside from [`browser`, `by`, `element`, `element.all`, `$` and `$$` global syntactic sugar](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/webdriver-vs-protractor.md) and multiple unique locators and an easy way to add custom locators, there is a set of built-in [Expected Conditions](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) that are used with `browser.wait()` and help to sync with non-angular apps.

Also, don't forget about the convenient way to [configure your `protractor` tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js).

Also, there are several built-in [plugins](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) that extend protractor's built-in features. Currently there are Accessibility, Timeline, ngHint and Console plugins implemented.

---

In other words, with `protractor` you'll get everything that pure vanilla webdriver provides and much more on top.

---

Also, see:

- [Protractor vs Selenium. Which is easier?](http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/protractor-vs-selenium-which-is-easier)
- [Protractor - Testing Angular and Non Angular Sites](http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/)